# Looking for a course on character animation

Tags: animation

I am looking for recommandations on character animations courses on Blender. I am currently following the course "Ultimate Blender 3D Character Creation & Animation Course" but I am looking for something more in depth on the animation workflow, explanations on the different views and so one, not just following what the teacher says without always the explanation of the why. It is just my personal expectations obviously.

I followed the character creation from grant Abbitt which was really great but more focused on the sculpting (This teacher is a one of my top teacher as Darrin lile, Blenderfuru, and josh gambrell are in their own domain).

So if any one has a suggestion to a course (free or not), ideally with Blender 2.8 or higher as I started my Blender experience with this version, this would be very appreciated.

Comment: maybe ask the question on the blender artist forum: https://blenderartists.org/c/support/9

Comment: Thanks, I'll will!